# Horizontal movement with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I feel like a complete klutz, I had this working and then I accidentally forgot to save it! I'm an idiot. I've spent the last day trying to recreate what I had but I can't do it. Basically (from my last save) I had this:

```
function canvasMove(e) {

    if(!e) var e = window.event;

    var downcheck;
    var upcheck;
    var leftcheck;
    var rightcheck;

    if(e.keyCode == '38') {

        if(up + down == 0) downcheck = false;
        else downcheck = true; 

        e.preventDefault();

    } 


    if(e.keyCode == '40') {

        if(up + down > HEIGHT - 110) upcheck = false;
        else upcheck = true; 
        e.preventDefault();
    } 


    if(e.keyCode == '37') { 

        if(left + right == 0) rightcheck = false;
        else rightcheck = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    } 


    if(e.keyCode == "39") { 
        if(left + right > WIDTH - 110) leftcheck = false;
        else leftcheck = true; 
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(leftcheck == true) { left += 10; counting() };
    if(rightcheck == true) { right -= 10; counting() };
    if(upcheck == true) { up += 10; counting(true) };
    if(downcheck == true) { down -= 10; counting(true) };

}
```

The problem of course being that Javascrpt doesn't support the ability to check if two keys are being pressed at the same time. What I want to accomplish is when the user pressed up and left they'll move diagonally. Ignore the "counting" function, it's just to keep track of how much the user has moved.

I managed to accomplish this with just else and if statements, no less! So I was wondering if you guys could give it a shot. The first if statement in each key if statement is so the user can't leave the canvas box. Then I have a function that moves the user by redrawing the canvas.

```
function redraw() {
    clear(draw);
    draw.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    draw.fillRect(left + right, up + down, '100', '100');   
}
```

The "clear" function is just a simple function that clears the entire canvas. This is all controlled by an init function that looks like this:

```
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('game');
    HEIGHT = canvas.height;
    WIDTH = canvas.width;
    draw = canvas.getContext('2d');

    setInterval(redraw, 30);

    document.onkeydown = canvasMove;
}
```

Comment: "The problem of course being that Javascrpt doesn't support the ability to check if two keys are being pressed at the same time. What I want to accomplish is when the user pressed up and left they'll move diagonally."

Comment: Are you saying that you had previously succeeded in having the browser recognize multiple concurrent keypresses? It's still not clear what it is you're looking for. Does some existing code not work?  If so, exactly what part of the code?

Comment: Yeah. I had it working but I can't remember what I did. I was wondering if anyone else could have a stab at it or perhaps come up with a better solution. I've already explained, I want it to be able to move horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your -check flags need to be global variables rather than function-scoped variables, otherwise they will never stay set between keydown events (handling only one key at a time). You also need a keyup event handler that will unset the correct flag when a key is released.

Comment: Damn! I my problem was I didn't realise the difference between global and local variables. In my original version I'd been using global variables, and in this one I'd been using local ones. 

You live and learn, eh?